# Как вызвать мутацию из экшена

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Использую Vue.js, имеется вот такой actions:

```
 actions: {
     chmy(store, i){
      store.state.controls[i].isActive = true;
      store.state.controls[i].isValid = store.state.myinputs[i].regexp.test(store.state.myinputs[i].value);
   }
```

При запуске кода Vue.js ругается, что

```
Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

Как лучше всего написать мутацию? Ведь мне ещё нужно передать индекс массива controls i.

Попробовал так:

```
  actions: {
    chmy(store, i){
      store.commit('updControls', {control: store.state.controls[i].isActive, val: true});
}
}

  mutations: {
    updControls(state, obj){
      obj.control = obj.val;
    }
}
```

но не работает. подскажите как правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mutations: {
    chmy(state, i){
        state.controls[i].isActive = true;
        state.controls[i].isValid = state.myinputs[i].regexp.test(state.myinputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

И вместо action сразу вызывать мутацию

Если нужно именно через action

```
actions: {
    chmy(store, i){
        store.commit("updControls", {
            index: i, 
            value: {
                isActive: true, 
                isValid: store.state.myinputs[i].regexp.test(store.state.myinputs[i].value)}})
            }
        }
    }
},
mutations: {
    updControls(state, {index, value}) {
        state.controls[index] = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    actions: {
        chmy({commit}, someObject){
          commit('updControls', someObject);
}
    }

  mutations: {
    updControls(state, someObject){
      state.someStateObject = someObject;
    }
}
```